# Initializing and declaring a character array in C

Tags: c, character, character-arrays

This works.

```
char s[] = {'\x20', '\x09', '\x0a', '\x0d'};
```

These don't because "error: expected expression before ']' (or '}') token":

```
char s[4];
s = {'\x20', '\x09', '\x0a', '\x0d'};

char s[4];
s[]= {'\x20', '\x09', '\x0a', '\x0d'};

char s[4];
s[4]= {'\x20', '\x09', '\x0a', '\x0d'};
```

Is there any correct way to define and initialize on two different lines without using indices? I know I can say:

```
char s[4];
s[0] = '\x20';
s[1] = '\x09';
s[2] = '\x0a';
s[3] = '\x0d';
```

But out of curiosity, am I missing something trivial or is this unavoidable in C?

Comment: The question is, _why_ would you need to do this on two different lines?

Comment: Defining a struct then using it.

Comment: There is no struct here. These are character arrays.

Comment: Structs and arrays are initialized differently, after different sets of rules. Furthermore, you commonly use typedefs together with structs, but not with arrays.

Comment: My question gets to the core issue of my misunderstanding. It has been simplified to target this. The answer to this question has taught me how I can define a character array in a struct then initialize it elsewhere in my code, where my struct is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char s[] = {'\x20', '\x09', '\x0a', '\x0d'};
```

As you see the size of the array is not specified so you need to have initializer here and based on the initializer the size of the array is calculated and stored on stack.

Even if you have

```
char s[4];

s = {'1','2','3','4'};
```

This will not work because in C the standard says **Arrays are not assignable**

If you need to initialize then do it during declaring as already you are doing else fill in the array char by char or use inbuilt functions like `strcpy()`

Comment: It also won't work because `{1,2,3,4}` is not an expression. If you had `typedef struct {char a,b,c,d;} char4;` then you could do `char4 c; c = (char4){1,2,3,4};`

Comment: @rici Yes here there is a new-type with typedef but array name can't be a assignable lvalue

Comment: @JeremyRosenberg no probs

Comment: @Gopi; I know. My point is that you need the explicit cast `(char4)` before the brace expression in order to use a braced-literal. In C99/11. I could have made a struct from the array -- `typedef struct {char a[4];} char4;` but then gcc/clang will annoyingly whine about missing braces, insisting on `char4 c; c = (char4){{1,2,3,4}};`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>

char s[5];
strcpy(s, "\x20\x09\x0a\x0d");
```

Comment: Thank you, others have answered similarly, but you showed the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign like that without index after declaring.

So you can assign like that using the combination of `strcpy` and `strcat`.

For first one you can use `strcpy`, then strcat.

```
strcpy(s,"\x20");
strcat(s,"\x09");
strcat(s,"\x0a");
strcat(s,"\x0d");
```

Or else use the `strcpy` for copying the whole content in one time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Gopi answered similarly before you however.